# checkDirty always returning true

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

Whenever I call checkDirty() I am always getting true. Run the example below and just click the destroy button.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4t72c4n1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    CKEDITOR.config.autoUpdateElement = false; 
    CKEDITOR.on('contentDom', function (event) {

                        event.editor.resetDirty();
                    });
    CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (event) {

         event.editor.on('contentDomUnload', function (destroyevent) {
             alert('isdirty: ' + destroyevent.editor.checkDirty());
         });

    });
    $("#item_ckeditor").ckeditor();
    $("#item_docompare").on("click", function (event) {

        var $textarea = $("#item_ckeditor"),
            editor = $textarea.ckeditorGet();


        editor.destroy();

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I have a new isdirty function [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4t72c4n1/6/) that will return an accurate value for if the user has changed the content in the CKEditor. This will not always return true and will still work with the element attributes being automatically sorted.

```
    var isdirty = function(ckeditor) {
            return ckeditor.initialdata !== ckeditor.getData();

        };
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (event) {
        event.editor.initialdata = event.editor.getData();
    });
```

**Original**

Looks like there was a space added in the content automatically by the CKEditor so checkDirty() always returned true. I wrote my own function that ignores case and trims the spacing that was added automatically [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4t72c4n1/4/).

This works perfectly fine, UNLESS you set allowedContent to true and disable the ACF. The new problem is that CKEditor sorts the attributes on elements which causes check for modified content to not work properly.

I logged a separate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29019398/516492) to find out how to disable sorting of element attributes.

```
 var isdirty = function(ckeditor) {
     var originalcontent = $.trim(ckeditor._.previousValue.toLowerCase());
         newcontent = $.trim(ckeditor.getSnapshot().toLowerCase());
     return originalcontent !== newcontent;

};
```

Comment: As I replied in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29019398/disable-sorting-of-element-attributes/29029313#29029313 your approach is incorrect.

Comment: Down vote for copying the original code from the original checkDirty() and proposing a solution to trim the extra space?

Comment: My mistake. I mistaken `this._.previousValue` with `this._.data`. I can't undo my downvote unfortunately.