# Disable sorting of element attributes

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

Is there a way to disable the sorting of element attributes so that checkDirty() will work correctly when allowedContent is set to true?

Example of the sorting of attributes [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4t72c4n1/3/)

```
<div zattribute='z' attribute='a'>simple</div
```

gets changed to

```
<div attribute="a" zattribute="z">simple</div>
```

causing the checkDirty() call to always return true even though the user didn't actually change anything within the ckeditor user interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev ) {
    ev.editor.dataProcessor.writer.sortAttributes = 0;
});
```

will disable attribute sorting for all editor instances on the page. This is not covered anywhere in CKEditor docs and was found by reviewing editor instance object.

Comment: Thanks Den great find. I switched to use TinyMCE instead because it changes my content a lot less and the developers are far less resistant to the fact that changing the content unnecessarily like sorting attributes is not acceptable.

Comment: This is not working for me and it is even worse with this option : for a `a` tag it reverse `target` and `href` attributes from original order

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29019338/516492) is what I ended up using based on Reinmar's suggestions.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4t72c4n1/6/)

```
var isdirty = function(ckeditor) {
        return ckeditor.initialdata !== ckeditor.getData();

    };
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (event) {
        event.editor.initialdata = event.editor.getData();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does strange things like calling `editor.resetDirty()` on `editor#contentDom` (what for?). Additionally, CKEditor does not sort attributes, because the only thing that `getSnapshot()` does is taking the editable's `innerHTML`. So if anything sorts attributes it's browsers and if they do this (I remember that some do this randomly), then there's nothing you can do.

You need to start from scratch. Define first what you want to achieve and do this with least code possible. I would also advise you to not use `editor.checkDirty()` because it's a legacy method that won't work in specific cases (yes, this is missing in the docs). Use `editor#change` to get live notifications about changes, or simply compare `editor.getData()` from time to time.

Comment: I added editor.resetDirty() to ensure the _.previousvalue was set AFTER the html is automatically processed (I didn't see anything in the document for when that value is set so that I can use the checkDirty method). If developers shouldn't use checkDirty() then I think the document should be updated. I thought I could use it to check if the content was changed by the user. I have an updated isdirty function based on your suggestions. https://jsfiddle.net/4t72c4n1/5/

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of sorting the element attributes. My clients will be wondering why it shows up in the version comparison tool provided to them. It will be reordered even when they don't change anything.