# ckeditor seems to re-order elements

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

When inserting into [CKEditor 4](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/), it seems to be re-ordering elements.

For example, I put the content into an alert to see and here's how it should look:

```
<div class="youtube-embed-wrapper" data-video-url="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/EG05-Y_C4EU?rel=0" data-video-preview="/cache/youtube_thumbs/1b6e910f6416a7c24e151551dc4ef844.jpg" style="position:relative;padding-bottom:56.25%;padding-top:30px;height:0;overflow:hidden"><iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/EG05-Y_C4EU?rel=0" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%"frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

Yet when actually inserted, it ends up like this:

```
<div class="youtube-embed-wrapper" data-video-preview="/cache/youtube_thumbs/1b6e910f6416a7c24e151551dc4ef844.jpg" data-video-url="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/EG05-Y_C4EU?rel=0" style="position:relative;padding-bottom:56.25%;padding-top:30px;height:0;overflow:hidden"><iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="360" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/EG05-Y_C4EU?rel=0" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%" width="640"></iframe></div>
```

As you can see the data-video-url and data-video-preview tags have been swapped and I can't find out why.

It's using standard CKEditor functions when inserting (where "content" is the first quoted code above):

```
var element = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml(content);
var instance = this.getParentEditor();
instance.insertElement(element);
```

Has anyone else seen this before? I tried searching but I can't find anything on it.

Comment: What's the problem with how it's actually inserted?

Comment: The data-video-url and data-video-preview tags have been swapped and I can't find out why.

Comment: All of the html attributes have been sorted in alphabetical order. The question is why does this matter?

Comment: It's being picked up later by regex to replace it with a cookie acceptance bit for GDPR if people haven't yet accepted cookies, so the order matters.

Answer (score 1):

To disable sorting of HTML attributes, use:

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev ) {
    ev.editor.dataProcessor.writer.sortAttributes = 0;
});
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41202438/1911755

Comment: Additionally, this doesn't entirely solve it. It still seems to do some re-ordering when you view source and back to WYSIWYG again.